# Why does a function containing .click executes without clicking in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simplify my code. I would like to write a function with an event handler inside, where I can input parameters quickly and eliminate a bunch of extra typing (after several hours of coding it really makes a difference to me). As examples, I created a "shortcut" function for the .html method (which works fine) and one for a .click event handler. However the .click function executes without the user clicking anything. I can't figure out why.

[Here is  a JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/xx9oqeus/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>

    <h1 style="background-color:#555">-.-</h1>

    <button id="bu">How's awesome?</button>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var h1 = "h1";
    var bu = "#bu";
    var awesome = "You are awesome!";

    function html(a,b) {$(a).html(b);}

    function yaa() {html(h1,awesome);}

    function clickIt(a,b) {$(a).click(function(){b;})}

    clickIt(bu,yaa());

    // $(bu).click(function(){yaa();})

    </script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. check your code again and use JSFiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function instead of passing by reference

```
function clickIt(a,b) {$(a).click(function(){b();})} // here

clickIt(bu,yaa); // not here
```

You can optimize this a bit by then passing `b` by reference, and jQuery will call it.

```
function clickIt(a,b) {$(a).click(b)}
```